# Selections on Dimensions from Hypercube Qlik Sense Mashups

Tags: javascript, qliksense, hypercube

I am trying to do some selections on dimensions grabbed with a hypercube.

I got all the dimensions from the hypercube which is surpressing 0 and missing values, and I created a JS Object to make everything easier to get/understand.

It looks something like this:

```
{

    Date: Array          //Dimension1

     0: "01.06.2018"

     1: "02.06.2018"

     2: "03.06.2018"

     3: "04.06.2018"



     Category: Array          //Dimension2

      0: "Kat1"

      1: "Kat2"

      2: "Kat3"

}
```

As I said I am trying to do some selections on these Dimensions so I used the following

```
//this is an example so <Date> can be
app.field("Date").select( [0,1], true, true ).then(function(obj){                replaced with <Category>

     console.log("Success");

}
```

The problem is that no Selection is applied, the Objects look the same. The promise is never got.

In the same Qlik Sense Mashup I also have some Fields. So I thought...lets try a the same method on a field and not on a dimension...and it totally worked...the Objects changed.

So I thought...maybe I am doing something wrong...maybe you can't do selections on Dimensions...so I went to Qlik Sense Desktop and with Master Items I created a filterPane for the same Dimensions and I believe using Qlik View, I filtered the Values showed by the Objects in my Page using a selection made in the filter pane.

Any suggestions? I really need some help with this.

Many thanks!!

Alex

Comment: Have you tried `app.field("Date").selectValues(["dd/mm/yyy"], true, true);`?, where `"dd/mm/yyy"` would be an actual date value, I would create an array of values to select instead of an array of objects. But if you want a better answer you'd have to post your attempt so I can provide better feedback and an actual answer